# How to append html only if the div is empty in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code for displaying content for login and registration in my PHP file:

```
<?php // LOGIN PART ?>
<div class="login-part"></div>

<?php // REGISTRATION PART ?>
<div class="registration-part"></div>
```

And this in my js file:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
            // FOR REGISTRATION
            $('span.logreg.reg').click(function () {

                $('div.registration-part').append('<p>Registration</p>');
            });

            // FOR LOGIN
            $('span.logreg.log').click(function () {

                // insert html
                $('div.login-part').append('<p>Login</p>');
            });
        });
```

Now, everytime I click on a span it shows the text login or registration, according to which of the span was clicked.

Thats OK, however I need to add it only once, so when the user click more times on the span it will be not adding more text.

Remove() or empty() is not an option, as far as I know, because I need the information inside input boxes (there will be input boxes later for inserting user info) to stay there and not be deleted if the user click accidentally on the span again.

It can however delete the html inside the div, if he clicks on another span. E.g. if span.log is active, after clicking on span.log nothing happens, but if he clicks on span.reg the html inside div.login-part will be removed and registration text will appear.

How to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try APi: `.one` please :  (Reading your question it seems you only need to append the HTML like `login` once using `.one` will resolve this issue)

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element.

APi link: http://api.jquery.com/one/

This way append will only one time as desired and you will not have duplicate html showing multiple times.

Hope this helps, please lemme know if I missed anything,

**further** bit diff demo: http://jsfiddle.net/avSDa/9/ using `.is(:empty)` which ever suits you.

**code**  like this

```
  $('span.logreg.log').one('click', function () {

                // insert html
                $('div.registration-part').append('<p>Login</p>');
            });
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks I will try, but I am concerned what will happened if I click on login then registration and then go back to login.

Comment: @johnnyb3000 you will add `one` event to registration as well I will flick you a demo soon `:)` Let me know I will help you out.

Comment: Yes, it is working, but when I click at login and then registration and agian on login, it goes wrong. I need to reset the one () handler of login  when I am inside registration, so when I return(click) to login it execute the function as if it was for the first time. How to make such hack?

Comment: @johnnyb3000 cool man can you try this **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/avSDa/9/ ; also make me a demo if you want to explain whats wrong with one please `:)` Note I am using `.is(:empty)` to do empty check, else feel free to explain the issue further, will help you out!

Comment: Thanks, if($('div.login-part').is(':empty')) does it ;)